# How Check if email is opened with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, html-email

I would like to know if I can add JavaScript on my email that would communicate with my api to know if the email was opened by the user

Comment: Email clients typically disable Javascript precisely in order to prevent such things.

Comment: No decent email-client will execute javascript ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: you can **not**.

Every e-mail client will block any JS (that is all `<script>`s but also `onclick=`, `onload=` attributes etc.) in e-mails for **safety** and **privacy** reasons.

The only option available is to use an image like:

```
<img src="https://example.com/email-opened.php?id=453254">
```

...but some e-mail clients will block remote images by default as well.

Comment: They do block it also by creating theirs  or let me say they clone what is in the url

Comment: As I said: _„some e-mail clients will block remote images by default as well”_, unfortunately, there is no 100% sure way. JS will never work, images sometimes (depending on settings of an e-mail client).